# How to deploy sinatra application just with thin?

Tags: ruby, linux, deployment, sinatra, thin

I've written a small application with Sinatra.

Now, in the root directory of this project, I run "thin start", and it works. This is just a small project and would only run in my local machine. So I need not to use Nginx and I plan just to use "thin".

Well, the applcation should run automatically when the server starts. How could I accomplish this?

I have run:

```
sudo thin install
sudo update-rc.d -f thin defaults
```

And it seemed that thin could run automatically However, where could I config this to run my application?

Eh....Maybe this question have nothing to do with sinatra or thin. I just need something automatically run when the machine starts. I'm not familiar with Linux o(////)o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you need place config files into /etc/thin/
I think you can find example in /etc/thin/thin.yml

```
--- 
user: www-data
group: www-data
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
socket: tmp/sockets/thin.sock
chdir: /path/to/your/apps/root
tag: a-name-to-show-up-in-ps aux
```